# Does cellphone 4G tethering wifi cause the Ledger 'transaction rejected by server' error?

Tags: transactions, network, ledger-nano-s, server-side, transaction-propagation

I have just tried once again to make an ETH transaction using the default suggestion of 45 Gwei, which [seems much too high](https://ethgasstation.info). Yet it was rejected by the server, and the Ledger support has only emailed me so far that I should increase the gas! Even though [a price 5 times lower is being confirmed quickly](https://ethgasstation.info)...

Could the problem be that I'm using a cellphone company's 4G tethered wifi connection for my computer? Can that cause a the server rejection error? Could the cellphone company be blocking a port? If I can download blocks to sync Ethereum Wallet (which I can), does that mean the cellphone company is *not* blocking any ports?

Comment: Do you have the transaction id?

Comment: Don't those only exist for transactions that were successfully broadcast to the network?

Comment: A bad connection can cause any kind of errors, and ISPs can block ports. Do you have the exact error message? Is your node fully synchronized? Because while still syncing some values might not be correct.